# How to 'pop' or 'shift' from jQuery set

Tags: jquery

In Javascript, arrays should have methods *pop* and *shift*.

However, JQuery objects seem to be missing these methods:

```
$('div').shift(); // Error, shift is undefined
$('div').pop(); // Error, pop is undefined
$('div').splice(); // Splice is OK actually
```

I wonder why these functions are missing - after all, the jquery object is just an array.

What's the easiest way of performing pop and shift functions on jquery objects?

Comment: jQuery object **is not an array** although it seems to be.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They're missing because a jQuery object isn't an Array.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.pop = function() {
        var top = this.get(-1);
        this.splice(this.length-1,1);
        return top;
    };

    $.fn.shift = function() {
        var bottom = this.get(0);
        this.splice(0,1);
        return bottom;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

**EDIT:**  `.slice()` doesn't modify the original object. Fixed to use `.splice()` instead.

Comment: @fudgey: Yes, that was a copy from my test page. Updating... Thanks. :o)

Comment: cool :)... but wouldn't it just be easier to use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) by itself?

Comment: @fudgey: Depends on what OP wants. If he's looking to actually replicate `pop` and `shift`, then they need to modify the original, and return the item removed. `slice` creates a new object representing a subset of the original. But in most cases, yes, `slice()` would do the trick.

Comment: OMG just use `$.fn.pop = Array.prototype.pop`

Comment: Completely bizarre that it's not an Array (or at least, _derived from_ `Array`) in the first place.  `jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop` it is.

Comment: It is returning the same element always.

Answer (score 16):

Your safest bet would be to just use:

```
[].pop.call($('div'))
[].shift.call($('div'))
```

If you want to use the exact syntax in your example you can augment `jQuery.fn`:

```
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;
```

The latter works well for the [mutator methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Mutator_methods). It'll work for the [accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessor_methods) and [iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) methods too, but be advised that many of those returns a pure array that you'd have to rewrap. Be aware that jQuery has is own version of some of these (e.g. [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [.slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), etc.) that you probably don't want to overwrite.

Comment: In order to wrap the return element in a jQuery object, this is what I did: $.fn.arrayShift = [].shift;
        $.fn.shift = function() {
            var element = this.arrayShift();
            return $(element);
        };

Comment: yes ... in order to get back an jquery object need to do $([].pop.call($('div')));

Answer (score 7):

This seemed to work for me:

```
var divArray = $('div').toArray();
var elem = $( divArray.shift() );
```

`.toArray()` return the DOM elements as a JavaScript Array, which can be used as intended. Then all you need to do is convert it back into a jQuery object.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer has already been selected, but here's another alternative that isn't too hard to remember, in case you don't want to worry about having to install plugins all the time.

```
$('div > :first').detach(); // shift
$('div > :last').detach();  // pop
```

By the way, I realize there are [performance issues with using :last selector as part of your primary selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) so you may want to consider doing something like this for pop:

```
$('div').children(':last').detach();
```

Comment: just a note, if someone else stumbles on this answer: detach() removes the element from the DOM, so it's probably not what you want to do...

Comment: Not to mention being dom reflow intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $firstDiv = $( $('div').splice(0, 1) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way using `jQuery 1.9.1+`:

```
$('div').first().remove();  
$('div').last().remove();
```

Comment: remove() removes the element from the DOM not the list.